# Does Qt-Webkit 4.8 supports Selenium-2.47.0?

Tags: qt, selenium, webkit, selenium-ide

I didn't found the exact support document of QtWebKit.

Could you please tell me, Does Qt-Webkit 4.8 supports Selenium-2.47.0?

Answer (score 0):

No direct relation between Qtwebkit and selenium atoms.

Atoms will matter to a Qtwebkit webdriver

https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver supports atoms 2.43.0